# Returning custom attributes in OAath access token

Tags: oauth-2.0

We wish to return custom attributes from LDAP server as part of OAuth access token.

1. Is this possible.
2. Is it advisable? Is it a valid use of OAuth? Does the RFC discourage it?

I could not find a concrete answer, please avise.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can add custom attributes in addition to standards properties like , (access_token,refresh_token, expiry) etc.

The spec does not impose strict property usage , check the sample response mentioned in spec [OAuth2 Spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2)

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes
2. Yes

It's indeed both possible and advisable, for example the spring security implementation provides an interface allowing to enrich the access token with custom properties.

See http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/TokenEnhancer.html